# Prove $-(\frac{kv+g}{k^2})e^{-kt}-\frac{g}{k}t+(\frac{kv+g}{k^2})<vt-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ for $k,v,g,t>0$

Tags: inequality

How do you prove the inequality $-(\frac{kv+g}{k^2})e^{-kt}-\frac{g}{k}t+(\frac{kv+g}{k^2})<vt-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ for $k,v,g,t>0$ and $-(\frac{kv+g}{k^2})e^{-kt}-\frac{g}{k}t+(\frac{kv+g}{k^2})>0$ ? An elementary proof is preferred.

This left side of the inequality represents the height of a particle travelling under air resistance. The right side of the inequality represents the height of a particle identical in all ways, except it does not have air resistance.$k$ is a parameter determining the force of air resistance. $v$ is the initial velocity of the particle. $g$ is the gravitational acceleration of the particle. $t$ represents the time that the particles have travelled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more conditions. It is not true at $t=0$, for example ($0 \not < 0$).

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, making an edit.

Comment: Trying to show a launched projectile, or something, with air resistance is always slower than in the ideal case?

Comment: @nayrb Yes, quite clearly.

Comment: Working with the integral form of the differential equations might be helpful. Or come up with a differential equation for the difference of the two trajectories, and show that it is decreasing and hence always below zero.

Comment: Hi namehere, it might be useful for you to provide some context in the main body of your question, as there are many fine mathematicians who might not do physics on a regular basis.

Comment: @anegligibleperson So you're suggesting me explain the significance of k,v,g,t? Alright I'll make an edit right now.

Comment: as Daniel Fischer points out in an answer, you've got a problem with signs here. v0 is positive ("up") but gravity goes down, so the velocity is going to change from positive to negative at some t, and the non-resistive one is going to accelerate down indefinitely which will make it's v less than the other resistive one's v.

You should re-state this with some absolute value or vector magnitude bars in there, and maybe requiring that the projectile be fired downwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging the inequality yields

$$\left(\frac{kv+g}{k^2}\right) \left(1 - e^{-kt}\right) < \left(\frac{kv+g}{k}\right)t - \frac{1}{2}gt^2.\tag{1}$$

So it's clear that it can only hold for small enough $t$, since the right hand side becomes negative for large $t$.

For small positive $t$, rewriting both sides as the integral of their derivatives shows the inequality follows from

$$\frac{kv+g}{k}e^{-kt} < \frac{kv+g}{k} - gt$$

or

$$gt < \frac{kv+g}{k}(1 - e^{-kt}).$$

Now, $1 - e^{-x} > x - \frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x > 0$, so

$$\frac{kv+g}{k}(1-e^{-kt}) > \frac{kv+g}{k}\left(kt - \frac{k^2t^2}{2}\right) = gt + kvt -\frac{(kv+g)k}{2}t^2$$

and $$kv - \frac{(kv+g)k}{2}t > 0$$ yields the inequality for

$$t < \frac{2kv}{(kv+g)k}.$$

The shape of the functions in $(1)$ makes it clear that there is exactly one $t_1 > 0$ at which equality holds, so $(1)$ holds for $0 < t < t_1$. Finding the (approximate) value of $t_1$, if desired, would probably best be done by a root-finding algorithm like Newton's method.

---

In response to the edit that the inequality should hold for

$$\varphi(t) := \frac{kv+g}{k^2}\left(1 - e^{-kt}\right) - \frac{g}{k}t > 0,$$

we see that the positive zero of $\psi(t) := vt - \frac12 gt^2$ is $t_0 = \frac{2v}{g}$. A computation (see below) shows that $\varphi(t_0) < 0$, so the positive zero $t_1$ of $\varphi$ is smaller than $t_0$, whence $\psi(t_1) > 0$.

Since $\psi - \varphi$ has only one positive zero<sup>(1)</sup>, it follows that $\varphi(t) < \psi(t)$ for $0 < t < t_1$.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> $(\psi - \varphi)''(t) = (kv+g)e^{-kt} - g$. In particular, $(\psi-\varphi)''(0) = kv > 0$, and $(\psi-\varphi)''$ is strictly decreasing with asymptote $-g$.

So $\psi - \varphi$ is strictly convex and strictly increasing for $t < t_2 := \frac1k \log \frac{kv+g}{g}$, and strictly concave for $t > t_2$ (still strictly increasing for a while). A strictly concave function that is positive at $x$ can have at most one zero larger than $x$.

---

Verification of $\varphi(t_0) < 0$:

$$\begin{align}
\varphi(t_0) &< 0\\
\iff \frac{kv+g}{k^2}\left(1 - e^{-2kv/g}\right) &< \frac{2v}{k}\\
\iff 1 - e^{-2kv/g} &< \frac{2kv}{kv+g}\\
\iff 1-\frac{2kv}{kv+g} &< e^{-2kv/g}\\
\iff \frac{g-kv}{g+kv} &< e^{-2kv/g}.
\end{align}$$

Now, if $kv \geqslant g$, that is obviously satisfied. Otherwise, let $x := \frac{kv}{g}$. We then need to see that

$$\frac{1-x}{1+x} < e^{-2x}.$$

This holds for $0 < x < 1$, since

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{ds}\left((1+s)e^{-s} - (1-s)e^s\right) =s(e^s - e^{-s}) &> 0\\
\Rightarrow \int_0^x s(e^s-e^{-s})\,ds &> 0\\
\Rightarrow \left[(1+s)e^{-s} - (1-s)e^s\right]_0^x = (1+x)e^{-x}-(1-x)e^x &> 0\\
\iff (1+x)e^{-x} &> (1-x)e^x\\
\iff e^{-2x} &> \frac{1-x}{1+x}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: My bad about not adding the correct conditions in the question. Corrected them.

Comment: I've added the proof that the inequality holds while the left hand side is positive.